# How can I sort the elements of a cell?

Tags: matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have a cell like this:

```
A{1,1}=[ 1 ;2; 3;];
A{2,1}=[ 4 ;2;];
A{3,1}=[ 3 ;2; 5; 4; 6;];
...
A{N,1}=[ 10 ;2;5; 7;];   %N is very large.
```

In other words, the number of columns in each element of this cell is different, with no definite pattern.

Now, I want to sort these elements based on the element at the **first column**. I mean, I want the result to be like this:

```
Asorted{1,1}=[ 1 ;2; 3;];
Asorted{2,1}=[ 3 ;2; 5; 4; 6;];
Asorted{3,1}=[ 4 ;2;];
...
Asorted{N,1}=[ 10 ;2;5; 7;];
```

Currently I use this function:

```
function Asorted = sortcell(A)
B=[];
nrows = size(A,1);

for i=1:nrows            % this for-loop is slow
    st=A{i,1};
    B(i,1) = st(1,1);
end
[sorted,indices] = sort(B);
Asorted = A(indices,:);
end
```

It works, but it takes much time. In fact the for loop part is very slow.
I read about cat function, but I don't know how to use it. I used `B = cat(1,A{:}(1,1));`, but there is this error: `??? Bad cell reference operation.`

**I wanted to know if there is a more faster way of doing this?**

Thanks.

**Update**
Lets do an experiment:

```
A={};
for i=1:1e3
    A{i,1} = ones(4,1) * randn;
end

N=1000;sum1=0;sum2=0;sum3=0;sum4=0;
for t=1:N

    % # Solution with for loop and no prealocation
    tic
    B = [];
    for i = 1:size(A, 1)
        B(i, 1) = A{i,1}(1,1);
    end
    [Y, I] = sort(B);
    Asorted = A(I,:);
    a=toc;sum1=sum1+a;

    % # Solution with for loop and Prealocation
    tic
    B = zeros(size(A,1), 1);
    for i = 1:size(A, 1)
        B(i, 1) = A{i,1}(1,1);
    end
    [Y, I] = sort(B);
    Asorted = A(I,:);
    a=toc;sum2=sum2+a;

    % # Solution with cellfun
    tic
    [Y, I] = sort( cellfun( @(x) x(1), A ) );
    Asorted = A(I);
    a=toc;sum3=sum3+a;
    tic

    % # Solution with for loop and ???
    for i = 1:size(A, 1)
        B(i, 1) = A{i}(1);
    end
    [Y, I] = sort(B);
    Asorted = A(I);
    a=toc;sum4=sum4+a;
end
```

and the result is
**sum1=2.53635923001387

sum2=0.629729057743372

sum3=4.54007401778717

sum4=0.571285037623497**

** Which means per-allocation is faster, but what is the 4-th method. I thought it deserves to be discussed in a separate question. see [Matlab Pre-allocation vs. no allocation, the second one is faster, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022979/matlab-pre-allocation-vs-no-allocation-the-second-one-is-faster-why)

Comment: your loop is very slow since you have not pre-allocated memory space for array `B`. Your way, at each iteration, Matlab has to re-allocate memory space for `B` that is one element bigger than `B` at the previous iteration. This cause Matlab a **significant** slow down. Pre-allocation of arrays is a very good practice for Matlab coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop is slow because `B` is growing inside it; you should preallocate memory for `B` and it should run significantly faster. To do this, insert the following line before the `for` loop:

```
B = zeros(nrows, 1);
```

You can further shorten your loop like so:

```
B = zeros(size(A,1), 1);
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    B(i, 1) = A{i}(1);
end
[Y, I] = sort(B);
Asorted = A(I);
```

#### EDIT

I decided to compare this solution with a shorter solution that employs `cellfun` (which I formerly proposed):

```
A = {[1; 2; 3], [4; 2], [3; 2; 5; 4; 6], [10; 2; 5; 7]};

% # Solution with a for loop
tic
for jj = 1:1e3
    B = zeros(size(A,1), 1);
    for i = 1:size(A, 1)
        B(i, 1) = A{i}(1);
    end
    [Y, I] = sort(B);
    Asorted = A(I);
end
toc

% # Solution with cellfun
tic
for jj = 1:1e3
    [Y, I] = sort( cellfun( @(x) x(1), A ) );
    Asorted = A(I);
end
toc
```

The results are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.028761 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.253888 seconds.
```

The loop runs by an order of magnitude faster than `cellfun`! This difference can be extremely noticeable for large arrays, so I recommend using a `for` loop in this problem.

Comment: +1 I was giving the same answer, but only 30 seconds after :S

Comment: @EitanT this is the answer to my question, but please read the update part and see the linked question there.

Comment: @Ron I can see that you already posted it as a new question, and there is already (a correct) answer for you. Anyway, when you calculate `sum4` you already use a preallocated `B` from the calculation of `sum3`, so that's why it is just as fast.

Comment: @EitanT thanks a lot, I thought this is something strange :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cellfun`

```
[~, I] = sort( cellfun( @(x) x(1), A ) );
Asorted = A(I);
```

Comment: I found that this is _by far_ slower than a loop.

Comment: @EitanT - I believe that current implementation of `cellfun`, `arrayfun` and some other `fun`s is far from ideal. However, the intention of Mathworks is to provide better (probably parallel) implementations of these functions. So, I guess it is a good practice to use these `fun`s hoping that in the future it will pay off. But you are right, if you are worried about running times more than you care about the "nicety" of your code - go ahead and `for`-loop this solution!

Comment: Well, the OP did state that his main problem was performance because N is very large, so I'd rather not incite him to use `cellfun`. I myself suggested this solution but then retracted it and changed it to a for loop instead.