# Matlab Pre-allocation vs. no allocation, the second one is faster, why?

Tags: performance, matlab

About three month ago, I was running a sample in Matlab and something strange happened. Today, while I was testing the answers to my other question ([How can I sort the elements of a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021238/how-can-i-sort-the-elements-of-a-cell)) that happened again. It is about pre-allocation in Matlab. Let me explain it:

Consider this test code in which we try to create a matrices (`ones(100,100)`) in three ways:

1. No pre-allocating (declaring `I=[]`)
2. With pre-allocation (declaring `I=zeros(100,100)`)
3. No allocation at all (I declare nothing)

Code:

```
N=1000;
sum0=0;sum1=0;sum2=0;
for q=1:N

    % No pre-allocating
    tic
    I=[];
    for i=1:100
        for j=1:100
            I(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
    a=toc;sum0=sum0+a;

    % with pre-allocation
    tic
    I=zeros(100,100);
    for i=1:100
        for j=1:100
            I(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
    a=toc;sum1=sum1+a;

    % if nothing is declared, I call it no-allocation
    tic
    for i=1:100
        for j=1:100
            I(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
    a=toc;sum2=sum2+a;
end
```

the results are:

```
sum0 =1.53790886830589    //no pre-allocation
sum1 = 0.127538555877912  //with pre-allocation
sum2 = 0.120887850271473  //no allocation
```

The third method (where I do not write `I=[]` or `I=zeros(100,100)`) is the best approach! This happened in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021238/how-can-i-sort-the-elements-of-a-cell) too. (see the update part)

**What is the difference between this method and the first and the second one?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third time you run the loop, `I` already exists in the workspace. Thus, the loop is as fast as the second one, except that you're not calling `zeros` anymore.

I suggest replacing `I` with `J` and `K` the second and third time to avoid errors when calculating timings (or call `clear I` before each loop; thanks @EitanT).

**EDIT** As an alternative, you can use implicit preallocation, where you loop backwards, so that the first element you assign defines the entire array:

```
for i=100:-1:1
    for j=100:-1:1
       I(i,j) = 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: ... or do `clear I` between sections to delete that workspace variable.

Comment: ha ha, So simple, never thought about that. So per-allocation is really important.

Comment: @Ron: In a simple (not double) loop, pre-allocation has gotten a little less important since R2012a, but it'll still make your code faster (and throw out-of-memory errors in a more sensible place).