# How can I read data in particular format to a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a text file FILE1.txt which has data logged in the format specified.

```
[39645212,-79970785]35892002323232[0.0][39645212,-79970785]35892002323232[12.2]
```

I would like to load this data into a matrix of size 2*4. I tried using dlmread which throws me errors. I am trying to get something using textread. How can I get something like:

```
39645212 -79970785 35892002323232 0.0
39645212 -79970785 35892002323232 12.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)

```
mat = []; % I am lazy and I do not per-allocate. this is BAD.
fh = fopen( 'FILE1.txt', 'r' ); % open for read
line = fgetl( fh );
while ischar( line )
    tks = regexp( line, '\[([^,]+),([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)', 'tokens' );
    for ii = 1:numel(tks)
        mat( end+1 ,: ) = str2double( tks{ii} );
    end
    line = fgetl( fh );
end
fclose( fh ); % do not forget to close the handle :-)
```

**NOTES:**

1. I assume no spaces and only numbers are between the '[', ']' and ','. So I can use `str2double` on the recovered strings.
2. I did not pre-allocated `mat` - this is bad practice and can significantly reduce performance. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049677/matlab-preallocation-guess-a-large-matrix-or-a-small-one) for details on how to pre-allocate.

Comment: hey Thanks.it worked. But the third cell value 35892002323232 comes as 3.5892e+014. Is there any way to get it in 35892002323232 format

Comment: You are dealing with very large numbers in floating point format. You might need to convert them to `int64` in order to maintain precision.

Answer (score 2):

```
fid = fopen('fun.txt'); %the file you want to read
A=fscanf(fid,'[%d,%d]%d[%g][%d,%d]%d[%g]',[2 inf]);
fclose(fid);
```

See [fscanf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) for syntax of the formatting string

Comment: Hey thanks for the response but this doesn't work. I am trying to see what the problem. Did it work for you

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is very specific, and so is my solution:

```
C = textread('FILE1.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
A = reshape(str2num(regexprep([C{:}], '[\]\[,]', ' ')), 4, [])'
```

This replaces all brackets and commas with spaces, converts everything to numbers and reshapes to a matrix `A` with 4 columns. It should work for an input file with more than one line as well.